# How to transform bytecodes to initialize primitive constants in static block with ASM?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I need to transform Java bytecode with ASM to initialize `public static final` fields inside a `static {...}` block in the class. For example:

Input:

```
public static final int CONSTANT = 10;
```

Output:

```
public static final int CONSTANT;

static {
    CONSTANT = 10;
}
```

I need this transformation because the compiler replaces primitive constants by their actual value in the bytecode, so their usage becomes untraceable. This transformation allows tracing the usage of constants.

Comment: I doesn’t help to change the declaration, unless you also recompile all classes using this constant. So if you are going to recompile your sources anyway, why don’t you make the specified transformation right in the source file…

Comment: @Holger: Because I don’t want to modify the source code. I need to do my transformations in the bytecodes, i.e. the deployed version of the Java artifacts.

Comment: But you do understand that changing this one class file is pointless, as the compiler’s behavior you want to alter has already taken place?

Comment: @Holger: Yes, It’s pointless to the artifact but not for their clients. Consider a Java artifact  A that has a class with such a public constants. If an artifact B that depends on A reuses such a constant, then there is no way to know that at the bytecode level without applying this modification. So, the question can be reshaped as: how to transform Java constants in such a way that their usage can be traceable at the bytecode level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such a transformation, you can use the usual `ClassReader` →`ClassVisitor`(transformer) →`ClassWriter` chain. There are three fundamental steps:

- Override `visitField` to track all fields with a constant value and call the super visit method without a constant, i.e. with `null`, to keep the field declaration but remove the constant value.
- Override `visitMethod` to notice whether there’s an already existing class initializer (`<clinit>` method). If so, return a special `MethodVisitor` which will inject the field initialization at the beginning of the code and clear the map so the third step becomes a no-op.
- Override `visitEnd` to create a class initializer if there were constant fields and no existing class initializer. The newly created class initializer has to do the same field assignments, so it’s worth having the common code in an `injectFieldInit` method. Then, we only have to append the mandatory `RETURN` instruction which we don’t need to add for an already existing initializer.

This code uses an array as map key, which is no problem here, as each field is distinct, so the fact that arrays have no content based `equals` method is irrelevant. We could have used a `List<Map.Entry<…>>` instead or a list of a dedicated element type for holding all necessary values, with the same result as the code does no lookup but only iterates over the discovered fields once.

```
public static byte[] transform(byte[] classFile) {
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classFile);
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
    ClassVisitor trans = new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, cw) {
        private String currClassName;
        private Map<String[],Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
        @Override public void visit(int version, int acc, String name,
                                    String sig, String superName, String[] ifs) {
            currClassName = name;
            super.visit(version, acc, name, sig, superName, ifs);
        }
        @Override public FieldVisitor visitField(int acc, String name, String desc,
                                                 String sig, Object value) {
            if(value != null && (acc & Opcodes.ACC_STATIC) != 0)
                constants.put(new String[]{currClassName, name, desc}, value);
            return super.visitField(acc, name, desc, sig, null);
        }
        @Override public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int acc, String name, String desc,
                                                   String sig, String[] ex) {
            MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(acc, name, desc, sig, ex);
            if(name.equals("<clinit>")) {
                mv = new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, mv) {
                    @Override public void visitCode() {
                        super.visitCode();
                        injectFieldInit(this, constants);
                        constants.clear();
                    }
                };
            }
            return mv;
        }
        @Override public void visitEnd() {
            if(!constants.isEmpty()) {
                MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(
                    Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "<clinit>", "()V", null, null);
                mv.visitCode();
                injectFieldInit(mv, constants);
                mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
                mv.visitMaxs(-1, -1);
                mv.visitEnd();
            }
            super.visitEnd();
        }
    };
    cr.accept(trans, 0);
    return cw.toByteArray();
}
static void injectFieldInit(MethodVisitor target, Map<String[], Object> constants) {
    for(Map.Entry<String[],Object> e: constants.entrySet()) {
        target.visitLdcInsn(e.getValue());
        String[] field = e.getKey();
        target.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.PUTSTATIC, field[0], field[1], field[2]);
    }
}
```